# PySpark join 2 dataframes and join the unmatched rows to a 3rd dataframe in a single line

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Is it possible to write a logic for multiple joins, in a way that in case the first join does not find a match then join those unmatched rows with a different dataframe. Is it possible to do this in a single line? The issue is with my solution that df2 and df3 have columns with same names(cityName for example). I can rename them, but in that case I will create separate columns for each join and the data should be in the same columns. My solution will create 2 cityName columns.

```
df1.join(df2, df1.locationCode == df2.airportCode, "left")
df1.join(df3, (df1.locationCode == df3.cityCode) & (df1.airportCode.isNull()), "left")
```

Comment: Did you try coalescing, coalesce(df2.cityName, df3.cityName) as cityName. This will make sure that if df2 has value then use it if not use value from df3

Comment: Should I use coalesce after the joins?

Comment: Yes, after the joins are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use leftanti joins for this. Something like:

```
records_that_match_df2 = df1.join(df2, df1.locationCode == df2.airportCode ,"inner")
records_that_match_df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.locationCode == df2.airportCode ,"leftanti").join(df3, df1.locationCode == df3.cityCode,"inner")
```

Or if you really need a single line:

```
all_records = df1.join(df2, df1.locationCode == df2.airportCode ,"inner").union(
    df1.join(df2, df1.locationCode == df2.airportCode ,"leftanti").join(df3, df1.locationCode == df3.cityCode,"inner")
)
```